# How to add custom slide to delete to a tableview which is inside a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an already completed screen in which I have added a listing using UITableView which is inside a UIViewController. Now, I have to add swipe to delete functionality. I see several swipe to delete implementations but all of them assume that UITableViewController is used. Is there a way I can get same functionality in my UITableView which is inside a UIViewController?

I have tried but I can't achive that goal.

Comment: Whether you use a `UITableViewController` or a `UITableView` there is no difference. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-swipe-to-delete-uitableviewcells

Comment: *"I see several swipe to delete implementations but all of them assume that UITableViewController is used."* - this is not true. None of them make such an assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a problem where my cells were not adjacent to the screen edges and there was some spacing so the default implementation would not look good.

So if you want to add swipe to delete functionality you can very easily add your own custom swipe to delete functionality by:

1. Adding swipe gesture to your table cell and set the correct direction.
2. Modify your table cell such that it has a delete button hidden at the far right behind the content.
3. Upon swipe, move your cells content such that the delete button becomes visible. A simple animation will add the effect of button revealing from the right side. Also fire a notification 'DidSwipeCell'
4. Now capture the delete button press event, you have to pass this information to the parent viewcontroller so that data can actually be deleted. This can be very easily achieved by a Delegate protocol.
5. Remove the item from data and cell from the table.
6. Add a notification observer in the cell to listen to 'DidSwipeCell' notification so that if any other cell is swiped, or if user cancels the swipe by tapping on the cell, swipe back the current cell.

Here is the my cell class with basic implementation:

```
// Delegate to let VC know about delete action
protocol NotificationTableCellDelegate: class {
    func didDeleteTapped(id: String)
}

class NotificationTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var contentContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var typeImage: UIImageView!


@IBOutlet weak var main_container_trailing: NSLayoutConstraint!
// id required to identify the cell/item, can be the database id of object or simply
// index
private var currentId = ""
// to keep track if cell is swiped or not
var swiped = false
// distance to slide to reveal delete button
var slideOffset = 60.0
// tap Gesture used to swipe-back to normal position
weak var tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer?

weak var delegate: NotificationTableCellDelegate?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    
    // Add swipe left gesture
    let swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didSwipeCell))
    swipeGesture.direction = .left
    self.contentContainer.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
    
    // Add notification listener for any swipe performed in the table
    NotificationCenter.observeNotification(name: AppData.internalNotifications.NotificationTableCellDidSwipe, observer: self, selector: #selector(handleSwipeNotification))
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    // on reuse, slide back
    self.slideBack()
}

// on delete, remove observer
override func delete(_ sender: Any?) {
    NotificationCenter.removeObserver(observer: self)
}

@IBAction func deleteButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    // let delegate know when cell is deleted, pass id 
    self.delegate?.didDeleteTapped(id: currentId)
}

@objc func didSwipeCell(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    // upon swipe, slide main container to reveal delete button
    self.slideMainContainer()
    // Add tapgesture on the sliding view so that if user
    // tap the cell, delete gesture is cancelled
    self.addTapGestureToContentContainer()
}

@objc func handleSwipeNotification(notification: Notification) {
    guard let currentId = notification.userInfo?["currentId"] as? String else {
        return
    }
    
    // if notification is from this very cell, return
    if !currentId.isEmpty, currentId == self.currentId {
        return
    }
    
    // if some other cell is swiped, swipe this cell back
    self.slideBack()
}

func slideMainContainer() {
    let constant = self.main_container_trailing.constant
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        self.main_container_trailing.constant = constant == 0 ? self.slideOffset : 0.0
        self.contentContainer.superview?.setNeedsLayout()
        self.contentContainer.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
        
        // Post swipe notification
        NotificationCenter.post(name: AppData.internalNotifications.NotificationTableCellDidSwipe, userInfo: ["currentId" : self.currentId])
    }
}

func addTapGestureToContentContainer() {
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(slideBack(animated:)))
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    
    self.contentContainer.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    self.tapGesture = tapGesture
}

func removeTapGestureFromContentContainer() {
    guard let tapGesture = self.tapGesture else {
        return
    }
    self.contentContainer.removeGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

@objc func slideBack(animated: Bool = true) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        self.main_container_trailing.constant = 0.0
        self.contentContainer.superview?.setNeedsLayout()
        self.contentContainer.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    self.removeTapGestureFromContentContainer()
  }
}
```

[image: custom swipe]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it inside UIViewController as well. You have to implement below 2 functions inside your UIViewController:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Implement delete functionality. 
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: These methods are specific to UITableViewController and cannot be overridden in a subclass of UIViewController.

Comment: This is not true it can be overridden in UIViewController with UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource. I am using it.

Comment: To avoid confusion... here, you are ***implementing*** those two `.dataSource` functions, not ***overriding*** them --- that's why the signature is `func tableView(...)` instead of `override func tableView(...)`